# How to use Azure AD authentication for separate non-Azure ASP.NET MVC web application and Web Api sites?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

We have the following:

- ASP.NET MVC 5 web application hosted on our company server (not Azure) e.g., ourcompany.com. This not an AngularJS or single page application.
- ASP.NET MVC WebApi 2 hosted on our company server (not Azure) e.g., api.ourcompany.com. This is a separate project from the web site so it can be accessed by multiple apps/sites.
- Azure Active Directory for our company

What we want to do is:

1. User visits web site and logs in via Azure AD authentication.
2. Web application renders pages w/ JavaScript.
3. Page JS calls Web API

I see the docs/samples in the Azure documentation for:

- Web App to Azure AD
- Web App to WebApi
- SPA to WebApi

If the API components were contained in the web application project the JS call from the page would have access to the user credentials. However, w/ the API separate, the questions is how to utilize the authentication in #1 to allow #3 to call the WebApi using JS and have access to all the authentication information?

Comment: Up'd it. I need to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a similar scenario to work by starting from the WebApp to WebApi sample using Azure AD and OpenID Connect.

[Calling a web API in a web app using Azure AD and OpenID Connect](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect)

The sample provides single sign on for the users on the web app and will delegate the user identity from the web app to web api.  It did so by retrieving a bearer token in the web app controller and using it to invoke the web api.
We can easily use the same bearer token to make a javascript ajax call by putting the bearer token on the Authorization header:

```
//jQuery example
settings.headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearerToken,
};
```

I was able to get this to work without adal.js liberary.  Cors is still needed to make the cross domain ajax call.